# Handeling different permissions per selected customer

Tags: openid, claims-based-identity, openid-connect, identityserver3, thinktecture-ident-model

I am going to implement a new login system for our new AngularJS application at work, using *IdentityServer3*, and *Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Owin.ResourceAuthorization.WebApi*.

Some users will have access to more than one customer.

I am trying to figure out the best way to give users different permissions within the same application, depending a selection in the frontend ( selected customer ).

Currently i am considering implementing my own permission service using webAPI. The frontend ask for all permissions using the current user's token and cache all permissions mapped to a customer in the frontend.

Can this be done in a good way using OpenID Connect?
I am thinking that implementing my own permission service is probably overkill or maybe i overlooked some clever way of using resource flow, or somthing like that.